# Authorization isn’t executed in laravel

Tags: laravel, authorization

[This is form ‘login’, when I’m enter information in input and after press button ‘login’ I move to page with audit where 0 is authorization isn't executed and 1 is authorization is executed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcVe8.jpg) I'm trying to create authorization in laravel.
I did it in other project in order to understand how it works and then all was good. Now I'm trying to transfer it in my main project but when I am logging in nothing work.
I don't have any mistake, authorization is simply not executed. I will grateful for any help.

Registration function

```
public function sub(ContactSignup $request){

    if(Auth::check()){
        return redirect(route('user.mainpage'));
    }
    
    $contact = new SignUps();
    $contact->name = $request->name;
    $contact->surname = $request->surname;
    $contact->age = $request->age;
    $contact->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $contact->email = $request->email;

    $contact->save();

    Auth::login($contact);

    if($contact){
        Auth::login($contact);
        return redirect(route('user.sign-up'))->with('success', 'Реєстрація пройшла успішно');
    }
}
```

Function login

```
public function subin(ContactSignin $request){

    if(Auth::check()){
        return redirect()->intended(route('user.mainpage'));    
    }

    $contact = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
    
    if(Auth::attempt($contact)) {
        dd(1);    
    }
    else {
        dd(0);
    }
    return redirect()->intended(route('user.mainpage'));
}
```

Web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('mainpage');
});

Route::name('user.')->group(function(){
    Route::view('mainpage', 'mainpage')->middleware('auth')->name('mainpage');

Route::get('/signin', function(){
    if(Auth::check()){
        return redirect(route('user.mainpage'));
    }
    return view('signin');
})->name('sign-in');

Route::post('/signin', [\App\Http\Controllers\ContactController::class, 'subin'])->name('sign-in');

Route::get('logout', function(){
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/');
})->name('logout');

Route::get('/signup', function(){
    if(Auth::check()){
        return redirect(route('user.mainpage'));
    }
    return view('signup');
})->name('sign-up'); 

Route::post('/signup', [\App\Http\Controllers\ContactController::class, 'sub'])->name('sign-up');
});

Route::get('/mainpage', function () {
    return view('mainpage');
})->name('mainpage');
```

Comment: what do you mean no thing works , do you mean you get error ? or you mean you can access the routes without authentication ?
and i thing you have syntax error , are you sour you have  dot after user word "user."?
please provide your end point route path and the error you got

Comment: “User.” isn’t syntax error. I’m always get 0. I don’t have any mistake in console. I edit my question and added photo, and description. Can you view?

Answer (score 0):

in your methods inside your controller you have  form request class called **ContactSignin**
in this class you have code

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }
```

make it **true**

The form request class  is responsible of validating your request ,
also contains an **authorize** method. Within this method, you may determine if the authenticated user actually has the authority to update a given resource
since you handle authorization logic for the request in the routes by provide
middleware('auth') it is no need to check for use authentication in your form request class

Comment: I changed this before, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

first you don't have route named ('user.mainpage') you have to define it in web.php
second , since you named your rout  in

```
Route::get('/mainpage', function () {
    return view('mainpage');
})->name('mainpage');
```

, you must redirect to the name of the route not to the path
for example if your route is `('/api/main')->name('main')` , you have to put the rout name in the redirect method , for example `redirect(route('main'));`

Comment: It didn't help. I still get 0 when I'm trying to authorization is execute